# Iterating through a multidimensional array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have a 3D numpy array I want to iterate through. If it's important, this is a .nii filetype (file used to store MRI brain data) and I used the nipy module to load these images, which can then be handled as numpy arrays to do image processing. I want to take the and go through the voxels and only include the voxels that have value < 2. Here is my attempt

```
import nipy

import numpy   

img = nipy.load_image('image.nii.gz')

img_manip = img.get_data()

result = numpy.zeros(shape = img_manip.shape, dtype = img_manip.dtype) 

for matrix in img_manip:

    for row in matrix:

        for item in row:

            if item < 2:

                result += img_manip
```

This SEEMS to work,but it's extremely slow, like it's still running now. I'm just wondering, is this the right way to do it? Should I have used np.empty instead? I'm not sure I'm still pretty noob at python.

EDIT: Just an FYI, the shape of img_manip is something like (368, 170, 32) and data type is float64

(Sorry I don't know how to make the code look "pythonic"!)

Comment: your code does something like `result = (img_manip < 2).sum() * img_manip` that is different from `img_manip[img_manip > 2] = 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem again! Haha, OK so it might not be PERFECT but it does the job. If anyone has a more elegant way of doing it please share! BTW this is not my solution, I actually asked the nipy mail list and they happily obliged to help me. Anywho, they suggested I take advantage of numpy's indexing system. So you would say:

```
img_manip[img_manip > 2] = 0
result = 15000 * img_manip #This is optional, just makes it into a nicer range for my purposes
```

Now for those interested, if you want to go back to .nii format, you could use the nifti package, see [here](http://niftilib.sourceforge.net/pynifti/), then you would simply do

```
new_img = nifti.NiftiImage(result)
```

And save your output!

EDIT: You could also use nibabel (and you probably should since it's being supported/developped further) by:

```
new_img = nib.NiftiImage(result)
```

Comment: Hi Norman, I like your question. I have just started working with MR data. I am now iterating through a DICOM file which has 15000 slices which are actually different dimensions of 43 actual slices. Can I ask you what software you use and why you use nifti? So far I have only used ptyhon with its pydicom module. I might take a look at nipy as well.

Comment: Hi Leo. I use nifti because FSL's output is in nifti. To visualize I use Amira, itksnap and FSLview. I personally haven't tried my hand with Dicom images yet, though nibabel and pydicom can go hand in hand. If you'd like me to try out a task, I would be more than happy to! Oh I've been looking into another cool software called Slicer and it integrate well with python too

Comment: Ah I'll import nibabel as well then! Slicer sounds handy too. Im still getting acquainted with all the aspects of handeling such big datasets. I wont be making 3D reconstructions, so I probably wont use FSL. I just installed NeuroDebian on my system because our admin was still busy getting me a MatLab key, but Im actually quite excited about it (and about python). If you want to exchange ideas or experiences please feel free to email me! I filled out my email adress in my profile so it should be visible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a potential solution to the original question, using `nibabel` and `numpy`:

```
import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np
img = nib.load('image.nii.gz')
data = nib.get_data()
data[data>2] = np.nan  # If you really don't want to look at these...
nib.Nifti1Image(data, img.get_affine()).to_filename('new_image.nii.gz')
```